# How to keep SVG radialGradient to be perfect circle in any rectangle without using gradientTransform?

Tags: html, svg, radial-gradients

Here's the SVG code:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 420 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <radialGradient id="gradient1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="20%" spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="darkblue" />
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="skyblue" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="darkblue" />
  </radialGradient>

 <rect x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150" fill="url(#gradient1)" />
</svg>
```

Since the width and height is the same the image looks like this: 
[image]

But when the rectangle becomes width="300" height="150" then it becomes like this: 
[image]

I found a solution by using gradientTransform and also by interpolating the header's cy and r like this:

```
<radialGradient id="gradient1"cx="50%" cy="25%" r="10%"
  spreadMethod="reflect" gradientTransform="scale(1.0, 2.0)">
```

This gives me a perfect circle like this:

[image]

However, I wanna ask if there is any other simpler method to this? Because I will need to make this dynamic in the code and we can get any kinds of dimension. Too much boiler plate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`. In this case the percentages are relative to the parent svg element.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 420 200" >
  <radialGradient id="gradient1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="20%" spreadMethod="reflect" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="darkblue" />
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="skyblue" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="darkblue" />
  </radialGradient>

 <rect x="0" y="0" width="350"  height="150" fill="url(#gradient1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but we don't want it to relative the percentage to the parent SVG element specially when we have more than a few rectangles in the space. But this is a good answer for a single rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out many things, I’m convinced there is no other way than to use gradientTransform. This is because we have more than one shape in the space. If I only have one shape then its more logical to use gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"

Hope this helps someone.